# Facebook scraper redirects page to about:blank and returns 404

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess

When someone hits the like-button on our website [randkrant.be](http://www.randkrant.be), Facebook is unable to scrape the page because it automatically redirects the page to "/about:blank" and returns a 404 error. There's no redirect to about:blank in the code or on DNS level.

In our htacces file we use the following rule to rewrite all incoming requests to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|png|jpg|css|pdf|doc|txt|htm|html|xml|ttf|flv|swf|xml|ics|zip|xls|csv|lol)$ index.php
```

Below the result of the Facebook developer debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=randkrant.be

Any idea what the problem might be?

[image]

Comment: Is this browser specific ? For example does this only occur in FireFox ?

Comment: No it's in all browsers. But only Facebook redirects this page, a regular user agent doesn't.